# Yii2 generic behaviour in all models

Tags: yii2, models, behavior

How Can I add a generic behaviour function that would work for all models. I have added this code in all models. Now I don't want to repeat the same function in all models.

Comment: try adding you r code to be more specific so that others can provide the answer that suits your requirments, you can create a base model class and add that function there and then extend all you models from that base model

Comment: I did not know where to begin as I had already had many models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `CustomModel` class that extends `ActiveRecord`. In `CustomModel`, add the method that you want:

```
class CustomModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
     public function custom_function() {
         //Function details
     }
}
```

Then make your models extend `CustomModel`

```
class Book extends CustomModel {

}
```

That way you can use this method in all your models that extends `CustomModel` without having to implement this method in each of them.

Comment: I think it should be `extends yii\db\ActiveRecord` for the base model `CustomModel`

Comment: do I have to do this for all existing models TIA

Comment: Suppose you have models Book, Car, and Pen. If you want to see this behavior in all those 3 models, then the 3 models should extend from CustomModel yes

Comment: Thankful. . Explicit and complete.